# Exponential number four not recognized in pdf generation with rotativa

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I have an MVC application in which I am generating PDF from HTML pages with Rotativa. In the HTML I display some strings which I take from the resources of my application. When they are displayed as simple HTML, all the strings look good, but when the conversion to PDF is made, the exponential values are not formatted properly.

For numbers less than 4, everything looks good, like `in²`, but when I am trying to display powers equal or higher than 4, (`in⁴`) the output is alterated like receiving a tilda `~` instead of the expected number. I assume this is because of the character set supported by Rotativa.

Is it possible to make Rotativa display exponential values higher than 3?

NOTE: I don't want to use `<sup> x </sup>` as it does not solve the problem of strings retrieved from resources.

I have tried changing the UTF enconding or font styles, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this with a work-around. After I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239134/split-exponential-number-string-representation-into-power-and-exponent) I understood how can I convert from exponential numbers, to simple string numbers, then used `<sup>exponent</sup>` I displayed the values from resources.

Not so pretty, but it's still working!