# Split exponential number string representation into power and exponent

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I have strings which come from resources in exponential form like the following: `2⁴`. I was wondering if there is a way to split this into:

```
var base = 2; //or even "2", this is also helpful since it can be parsed
```

and

```
var exponent = 4;
```

I have searched the internet and [msdn Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) also, but I was unable to find the solve for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add mapping between digits to superscript digits, then select all digits from source (this will be the `base`) and all the others - the `exponent`

```
const string superscriptDigits = "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹";
var digitToSuperscriptMapping = superscriptDigits.Select((c, i) => new { c, i })
                                .ToDictionary(item => item.c, item => item.i.ToString());

const string source = "23⁴⁴";

var baseString = new string(source.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
var exponentString = string.Concat(source.SkipWhile(char.IsDigit).Select(c => digitToSuperscriptMapping[c]));
```

Now you can convert `base` and `exponent` to `int`.
Also you'll need to validate input before executing conversion code.

---

Or even without mapping:

```
var baseString = new string(source.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
var exponentString = string.Concat(source.SkipWhile(char.IsDigit).Select(c => char.GetNumericValue(c).ToString()));
```

Comment: I will mark this as answer since it looks like the cleanest solution for my case. Thank you!

Comment: @meJustAndrew It is frustating being the first to answer and then being copy cutted with some added bells and whistle... and being ignored :(

Comment: @sam I know what are you saying, happend to me yesterday, I am sorry for this, but that was the most clean solution, and it is the answer to the question. To improve your answers and how you earn reputation, keep in mind that after you answer, you can continue editing, until it's the best for you can reach. Again, I am sorry for this!

Comment: @sam why do you think it is copy cutted? Providing normal answer takes a little bit more time + have a look at second option - it doesn't involves superscript digits mapping at all.

Comment: @AlekseyL. it was just the more direct way to explain the point, nothing personal. The core of the solution were all the same here. That's it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression together with `String.Normalize`:

```
var value = "42⁴³";
var match = Regex.Match(value, @"(?<base>\d+)(?<exponent>[⁰¹²³⁴-⁹]+)");

var @base = int.Parse(match.Groups["base"].Value);
var exponent = int.Parse(match.Groups["exponent"].Value.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD));

Console.WriteLine($"base: {@base}, exponent: {exponent}");
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your exponent is formatted is called superscript in English.
You can find many question related to this if you search with that keyword.

Digits in superscript are mapped in Unicode as:

```
0 -> \u2070
1 -> \u00b9
2 -> \u00b2
3 -> \u00b3
4 -> \u2074
5 -> \u2075
6 -> \u2076
7 -> \u2077
8 -> \u2078
9 -> \u2079
```

You can search for that values in your string:

```
Lis<char> superscriptDigits = new List<char>(){ 
    '\u2070', \u00b9', \u00b2', \u00b3', \u2074', 
\u2075', \u2076', \u2077', \u2078', \u2079"};

//the rest of the string is the expontent. Join remaining chars.
str.SkipWhile( ch => !superscriptDigits.Contains(ch) );
```

You get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex (if your source is quite clean):

```
string value = "2⁴⁴";
string regex = @"(?<base>\d+)(?<exp>.*)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(value, regex);

int b;
int exp = 0;

int.TryParse(matches[0].Groups["base"].Value, out b);

foreach (char c in matches[0].Groups["exp"].Value)
{
    exp = exp * 10 + expToInt(c.ToString());
}

Console.Out.WriteLine("base is : {0}, exponent is {1}", b, exp);
```

And `expToInt` (based on [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)):

```
public static int expToInt(string c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case "\u2070":
            return 0;
        case "\u00b9":
            return 1;
        case "\u00b2":
            return 2;
        case "\u00b3":
            return 3;
        case "\u2074":
            return 4;
        case "\u2075":
            return 5;
        case "\u2076":
            return 6;
        case "\u2077":
            return 7;
        case "\u2078":
            return 8;
        case "\u2079":
            return 9;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

This will output:

> base is 2, exp is 44